# How to iterate over split-up images efficiently with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

[image][image]I am studying information system engineering and need to suddenly use multi-threading/processing in my side job but we were never taught this at the university so I dont have any idea about it. I only read some introduction over the last couple of days. With that help I even got some simply test programs to perform better, but I wasnt able to do it for this task.

I have a picture with edges of objects as white dots (value 255 in an array).
Now I need to know the position in the array of these dots.

Because images are pretty large arrays and I need to optimize this for a raspberry pi I need to program this with multiprocessing in mind because in a test I only got exactly 25% CPU usage on the pi over 1 core and that was not enough for real time video processing.

```
def test_multi(self):
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
test_prep = self.test_prep.copy()
y, x = test_prep.shape
columns = []
for i in range(4):
    c = test_prep[0:y, 0:int(x/4)*(i+1)]
    c = copy(c)
    columns.append(c)
results = [pool.apply_async(search, args=(c,)) for c in columns]
for r in results:
    print(r.get())

def search(picture):
ys, xs = picture.shape
dots = []
for x in range(xs):
    for y in range(ys):
        if picture[y][x] == 255:
            dots.append((x, y))
return dots
```

But in the result list I can see that it is not really done in parallel because there are 4 entries and each one is just the last one plus some new dots from the next image part. So I think the processes wait for the one before to finish and only than add to the same list but I would like 4 separate lists that I will join afterwards. Also it takes a lot longer than just iterating over the picture the old fashioned way. So what is the problem ?

I tried switching around with multithreading but some people were saying that GIL would not allow the distribution over separate cores.

I tried reading the multiprocessing doc and found a lot of possibilities like queues, managers, pools and pipes but I don't really now what the differences are and when to use what.

I want 4 lists with coordinates of dots in the 4 different columns of the image and I want the search function to be performed in parallel distributed over 4 cores. Or another process that allows a 1920*1080 image to be search faster than in half a second.

**UPDATE:**

As Mark Setchell suggested I am using cv2.findContour() now but as I said sometimes it detects one contour as multiple ones so I added a routine that combines the middle of the contour that are very similar like this:

```
def search(image):
    ret, thresh = threshold(image, 0, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = findContours(thresh, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    objects = []
    for c in contours:
        objects.append(middle(c))
    any_neighbors = False
    while not any_neighbors:
        objects, any_neighbors = combine(objects)
    return objects

def combine(objects):
    ret = objects
    any_neighbors = False
    for o1 in objects:
        for o2 in objects:
            if is_neighbor(o1, o2):
                ret.remove(o1)
                any_neighbors = True
    return ret, any_neighbors

def middle(contour):
    xs = 0
    ys = 0
    size = len(contour)
    for c in contour:
        xs += c[0][0]
        ys += c[0][1]
    xs = int(xs/size)
    ys = int(ys/size)
    return xs, ys

def is_neighbor(p1, p2):
    return p1[0] - th <= p2[0] <= p1[0] + th and p1[1] - th <= p2[1] <= p1[1] + th
```

This might still not be perfect but im done for today. I'll be back tomorrow and check if the performance improvement is enough or if I still need to

Comment: What are you going to do with the dots when you have their positions? What else is in the image or are the dots on a black background? Please show your images.

Comment: The background is black. I use the position to find out which dots are neighbors so I can combine them to larger objects. The image I added is a test image I used . Thats how it looks like before edge detection but it is the same black background and white edge.

Comment: For the given image, is the answer that there are 3 dots, or that there are 29,264 white pixels? What are you planning to do with the answer as the next stage of your processing?

Comment: The overall answer is there are 3 objects at position "a,b,c". But the task I want to improve is return a tuple of tuples which contain the position of white pixels for example white_pixels = ((400,312),(405,316),...) this is easy but I wasn't able to split the image up and do this with multiple processes / cores simultaniously.

Comment: I suspect you are maybe barking up the wrong tree with looking for the dots first and running `for` loops. Have you look at OpenCV's `findContours()` https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: The thing is findContours() tends to think one contour is multiple ones. See in the new image added, I tried it with several test images. But if there are 3 markers present I need to know if it are exactly 3 because than I can do my triangle calculations.

Comment: Please provide the full-size image that `findContours()` has trouble with and details of what the problem is - at the moment there's only a small image that looks ok and some half-obscured code.

Comment: Note that if processing time is an issue, your blobs are very large so you could consider reducing the image size by a considerable factor (maybe 4-16 in each direction) and still find the blobs sufficiently accurately but much, much faster.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes I already do pyrDown() at the start but as I read your comment I do it one level more now and it still works and is faster.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I fixed that error now by combining contours that are very similar. I wrote it in the update ^^

Answer (score 0):

The process has become as fast as other parts of the program. Thats why multiprocessing wont be necessary anymore.